# Issue with TurnBased Multiplayer Game in Game-kit

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-center

I am working with cocos2d game in which i am implementing Game-kit. My game supports multiplayer option. Actually as given example [Raywenderlich link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5480/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-1). I am GKTurnBasedMultiplayer class from Game-kit. But now the issue when first player connected to game center and will select option of "Play Now" it automatches for another player. but issue is it directly connects and starts the match, and doesn't wait for another player. I am using

```
[[GCTurnBasedMatchHelper sharedInstance] findMatchWithMinPlayers:2 maxPlayers:4 viewController:viewConroller];
```

for connecting and playing with other players but directly connects the match.

I want to wait for another player.  That is the issue. I am also using GCTurnBasedMatchHelper Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your resource bundle id is the same as the iTunes Connect app you submitted...but my guess is you haven't done this?

https://developer.apple.com/support/resources/itunes-connect.html